# Increase tap area for UITapGestureRecognizer on UILabel when size of the label increases

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UILabel on the UICollectionViewCell. On the UILabel I've got a UITapGestureRecognizer attached. I'm trying to increase the tap area of the UITapGestureRecognizer on the UILabel when the width of the UILabel increases.

Here is the sample of the code:

```
class BusCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var bus: Bus!
    var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        addTapGestureToNameLabel()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UI
    
    func addTapGestureToNameLabel() {
        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(nameLabelDoubleTap(gesture:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        nameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        nameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    func configure(_ bus: Bus, isStereo: Bool = false) {
        self.bus = bus

        loadCellUI(bus: bus)

        bus.updateBlock = { [weak self] in
            
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            
            strongSelf.loadCellUI(bus: bus)
        }
    }
    
    func loadCellUI(bus: Bus) {
        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: yPosition, width: 122, height: self.nameLabel.frame.height)
                
        if bus.isStereo {
            if bus.index % 2 == 0 {
                let frame = nameLabel.frame
                nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: 244, height: frame.height)
                nameLabel.isHidden = false
                // Make the tap frame same as the nameLabel's frame
            } else {
                nameLabel.isHidden = true
            }
        } else {
            let frame = nameLabel.frame
            nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: 122, height: frame.height)
            nameLabel.isHidden = false
            // Make the tap frame same as the nameLabel's frame
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tap gesture recognizer attaches to a view, and responds to taps inside the frame of the view. It doesn't have a tap area of its own. If you increase the size of the label then the tap area should increase in size as well.

I remember reading a recommendation from Apple that a tappable area be at least 40x40 points. You might want to put an invisible view (call it `tapView`) on top of your label that is slightly larger than the label (You could get the label's frame, and call `CGRect.inset(by:)` with negative values for all the edges. Use the resulting rect as the `tapView`'s frame, and add the tap view on top of your label.) If you do that then you should put code in your view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method (and any time you change your `nameLabel` label)  to adjust the `tapView`'s frame.

Comment: After re-reading my answer, I would suggest something slightly different. I would add your tapView on top of your label view, and add AutoLayout constraints so that it is either centered over the label at a fixed size, or use top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints so it is slightly bigger than the label in all 4 directions. (You'll have to figure out how big the label is going to be, and how big you want the tappable area to be.)